# How to upgrade npm version

Tags: npm

I had npm version 3.5.2 installed and then I removed it by

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

And then I tried installing again by

```
sudo apt install npm
```

but still, the version is 3.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like repositories have an old version.

If you are using ubuntu try:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Or for node 10:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Tried it. I get a permission denied error, but I can still see that the version it's trying to install is 3.5.2

Comment: Are you using ubuntu? Probably the repositories being used are outdated

Comment: Edited the answer, can check it here too https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Answer (score 0):

If you already have `npm` installed, you can use it to update itself. The command for that would be `npm i -g npm`.